# Making an array with corresponding keys and values from array of strings

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to develop a page that will show a list of student ID's and their marks.

The page reads from a .txt file that contains comma-separated data:

```
12345678, 56

34567822, 67

12324654, 98

234769O1, 45
```

I extracted the data by reading the file line by line and storing the info into a pre-existing array:

```
while(!feof($handle)) {
        $value = fgets($handle, 1024);
        $students[] = $value;
    };
```

What I get from $students is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345678, 56

    [1] => 34567822, 67

    [2] => 12324654, 98

)
```

Is there a simple way of creating an array in which each student number becomes the key of its mark?

Comment: Which one is the student number?

Comment: @Andreas The first one I presume. It can't be marks.

Comment: Why are you not using `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: The long number is the ID, should've specified sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case `explode` is enough:

```
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $values = explode(',', fgets($handle, 1024));
    $students[$values[0]] = trim($values[1]); // use trim to remove extra spaces.
};
```

Comment: `explode(', '` and remove trim?

Comment: I prefer distinct `explode` and `trim`.

Comment: Feel free to accept any of the answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function for this.

```
$students = [];
if (($handle = fopen("marks.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $students[$data[0]] = $data[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

print_r($students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to convert the input into the structure you desire:

```
<?php
$input = [
    "12345678, 56",
    "34567822, 67",
    "12324654, 98",
    "234769O1, 45"
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    list($student, $mark) = explode(", ", $entry);
    $output[$student] = $mark;
});

var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(4) {
  [12345678]=>
  string(2) "56"
  [34567822]=>
  string(2) "67"
  [12324654]=>
  string(2) "98"
  ["234769O1"]=>
  string(2) "45"
}
```